# Remap Istanbul incorrect coverage report

Tags: webpack, istanbul, karma-coverage, karma-webpack, remap-istanbul

Running a **react redux app with typescript** i get **incorrect coverage** results when running **karma webpack with istanbul-remap** for mapping back to typescript source code.

For example i added a change to a react unit test that makes the code **not** go into the **mapStateToProps** and **mapDispatchToProps** anymore (ignoring the redux flow).
without using remap i get correct coverage decrease like so:

[image: correct coverage decrease]

with remap i get incorrect coverage result:

[image: incorrect coverage result]

Answer (score 0):

After changing the **webpack typescript loaders** from

```
loaders: ['react-hot', 'ts-loader']
```

to:

```
 loader: 'ts-loader'
```

in the webpack test config file i got coverage

[image: fixed coverage result]